# Are there electronic devices that can be used to replace hydraulic cylinders with short strokes

Tags: actuator

We use hydraulic cylinders in many applications to release brakes and clamp things. The choice of hydraulics is based on them being strong relative to their size. There are a couple of downsides with hydraulics though:

- Expensive cumbersome installation, sealings, long (expensive) holes as channels, hoses.
- Expensive drive unit that requires maintenance

I was inspired by [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/39770/16784) thread, where a solenoid was suggested. The problem is that my knowledge about electronics is very limited so I thought I should ask for suggestions here first.

Example of [hydraulic cylinder](http://www.roemheld.de/EN/roemheld.aspx?cmd=DETAILS&Article=1461001&csid=35&sm=)

- Ø22 mm (outer), length 38 mm
- Force ~3 kN at 250 bar
- For stroke ~1 mm will often be sufficient

**Operation**
We have tow scenarios where we use hydraulics:

1. For releasing brakes. The breaks are used for security when we have vertical loads. The brake is actuated by spring force but when the drive is powered up the brake is released by applying the force from the hydraulic cylinders.
2. For clamping tools. Normally the tools are clamped by spring force and released with force from the hydraulic cylinder when a new tool is mounted.

Both applications are very similar to the clutch in a car.

- Normally there will be only a couple of actuations per hour
- It is a simple motion no need for controlled acceleration/deceleration. Being able to limit the speed would be good for soft operation.
- I'm not even sure there is a need for a sensing feedback mechanism
- Regarding operation lifetime it is similar to the clutch in a car, it would be ideal to get 15 years of maintenance free operation

I struggled with trying to write this in English, please don't hesitate to as for clarification if something is missing or just strange/wrong.

Comment: What sort of speed of actuation do you need? For short-stroke applications particularly, have you considered leadscrews or rotary cams driven by small gearhead motors?

Comment: @DaveTweed Regarding speed it depends, if it is for clamping a tool 1 mm/s feels about right. Releasing a brake does not have to be fast but braking might need to be.
I have not seen leadscrews this compact and with this short stroke. Rotary cams sounds interesting, do you have a link or  recommendation for a brand?

Comment: Please share estimated actuations per minute, actuation speed, and expected operating lifetime, if you could. Is there any need for attenuation or controlled acceleration / deceleration? What is the extension sensing / feedback requirement or mechanism?

Comment: @SeeminglySo I added more details to my question, I don't have CAD available at home and don't know if it is possible to share considering NDA

Comment: On the rotary cam, no, I don't have any specific recommendations. I was just picturing something like the mechanism used on, for example, the cable-operated disk brakes for bicycles, but driven directly by a motor.

Comment: Implied in the description above but not explicitly in the requirements : the brake as described is failsafe; if you lose hydraulic pressure, it is spring activated to brake the system. Is that behaviour part of your requirements?

Comment: @BrianDrummond yes that is the way the brake is supposed to work. 
How strong is a solenoid btw? I looked a little at [piezo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectricity) elements but never found any with enough stroke.

Comment: Don't forget to consider **pneumatic** actuators as well, they may be a good alternative to hydraulic and electronic. (I use pneumatic devices a lot in some of my projects.) While pneumatic systems will require maintenance, compressed air, etc. you may find there is a cost savings over hydraulic depending on your application.

Comment: I am sceptical that you can replace hydraulics with solenoids in this application : small solenoids tend to be nearer 3N than 3000N. High force implies high current and a large structure (lots of copper!) - sorry I don't have numbers offhand. Plus for a failsafe you will need to supply current continuously during operation (unlike a hydraulic system where you only need to maintain pressure at zero flow). Pneumatic may be an option but usually operates at lower pressure; hence larger area for same force.

Comment: [Here][1] is Farnell's biggest solenoid, capable of holding at 218N. It can apparently pull 150N over a 1mm stroke, and requires close to 3 Amps at 12V. This is somewhat short of your stated requirements.


  [1]: http://uk.farnell.com/ledex/173921-023/solenoid-push-pull-continuous/dp/1331798

Comment: Consider a hybrid approach; if you controlled the hydraulics with solenoid-operated valves, could the hydraulic installation be made simpler, cheaper or more reliable?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and suggestions. Regarding pneumatics, space & force makes it non feasible for this application. Thanks for info on solenoid.

Answer (score 1):

Look at muscle wires / FLEXINOL. Wikipedia article is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape-memory_alloy). When current is passed through them, they shorten in length thereby generating a pull effect.

Data is available [here](http://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/141874.pdf)